# Manually getting the output instead of output redirection in cmd line

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program which has the prototype of the main function as follows:

`int main(int argc, char * argv[])`

The code hasn't been written by me, but this is a single C file available [here](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/c.txt). 
When I compile this code, and through the command line run it as:

`someexe in.txt > out.txt`
This gives me an output out.txt which is generated in the same directory by operating on some input from in.txt.

`someexe in.txt out.txt`
This gives me an output on the command line itself. (without using `>` operator)

However, instead of passing the command line argument and without using the output redirection `>` operator, I have been trying to call the main function from another function and passing the parameters myself. If I pass an array of `char*` {fileDirName, in.txt}, I am not sure how to go about generating an out.txt (since I think `>` output redirection is an operating system level function available in command line).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

The program in the link is readily available as copy paste and can be tried (main function is written at the last in the above program)

Comment: This really has got nothing to do with C++. Well, not much. Is this a Bash terminal we're talking about? (If you're on a Linux distro it probably is)

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Instead of the command line way, I am looking to do this in the program itself. So, I guess it is.

Comment: Calling main() again is *forbidden*.  A simple approach is to check if a second argument is specified and using that for output.

Comment: @HansPassant: I am actually this main function from another program (consider it as calling of a DLL's main function from another program and I am passing the parameters to this main function from there)

Comment: Ok, well you just want to use the function `stemfile` then, and throw away the existing `main`. I'd rather write it in C though, mixing both languages is very error-prone. To output to a file instead of `stdout` you need to replace `putchar` with `fputc` to a suitable stream.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really trying to achieve, but have you considered redirection using a pipe? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for a Windows example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the aim is to mimic the output redirection feature (`> out.txt`) of the shell you can do something like:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int fd = open("out.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0660);
  assert(fd >= 0);
  const int ret = dup2(fd, 1);  
  assert(ret >= 0);
  std::cout << "Hello redirected world!" << std::endl;
  close(fd);
}
```

You can do similar for stdin also, to mimic the input redirection (`< in.txt`). These will be preserved across calls to `exec()` too.

Of course it would be simpler to modify the program to write to the place you wanted given you have the source available.

Note though that `dup2()`, which "swap" the stdout fd for the one we just opened is non-portable. IIRC `open()` (as opposed to `fopen()`) is UNIX specific also)

Answer (score 0):

You can't call another main() from inside the source another program - main() is special.

If you want to reuse this source code as a library you need to rename main() to something else.

However if it is handling input from either a pipe or a file (eg `myprog < input.txt` or `myprog input.txt`) in the normal Unix way then that's a little trickier to handle transparently.

The best way would be to call the compiled program as a separate process from within your new program, passing the correct commandline parameters -  see the [exec() family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_%28operating_system%29) of calls